# Spring RestTemplate for post with multipart file and request paramters

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, multipart, http-request-parameters

I'm getting a controller with a multipart file and  string[].
I need to do a post method : using restTemplate.
Currently I can either send multipart file or string [] but not both.

```
Map<String, String[]> paramMap = request.getParameterMap();
MultiValueMap<String, java.lang.Object> body= new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("uploadFile", file);
for (String key : paramMap.keySet()) {
    body.add(key, paramMap.get(key));
}
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Comment: hi there new user. can you please provide a little more information?
what is the exception/warning/output you get? Also you are missing your headers in your source. 

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

Comment: Here is my header: 
`HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);`

My response was suppose to be "Item Added",

Comment: But im getting error msg as :
_`org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 null
 at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:79)
 at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:124)
 at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102)
 `_

Comment: I haven't really understood what you need to do, could you clarify?

Comment: Please EDIT your question to include this information. Also.. what is the content of 'url'?

Comment: @Gewure Unfortunately, being a new user. I cant edit my question.

@LppEdd: I need to make a post request from my controller of my springboot application to one rest api: `http://hostname/upload/` with one file (multipart) and few string as post form parameters. I'm trying to user restTemplate but facing this issue.

Comment: do you inject the resttemplate nicely and.. why is the port missing? are you using eureka as discovery service?

Comment: @GEWURE :yes it has port number 8085, just missed in comment above...